# Line structure of formaldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, lewis-structure

Would the line structure of formaldehyde, H2COH, simply be a straight line with a OH on the end of the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formaldehyde, $\ce{H_2CO}$, has the following structure

[image]

There is no $\ce{OH}$ group, just a central carbon atom with a single bond to each of two hydrogens and a double bond to oxygen.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I thought there was a hydroxyl group all of a sudden! Guess I was thinking of formic acid!

Answer (score 1):

When you omit the hydrogens, it would be a straight double line with an O at the end.